# TCPDF Creates Corrupted PDF Files

Tags: php, html, joomla, header, tcpdf

Well, now while writing these lines, I'm striking my head against the wall because of a silly problem that is not gonna be solved!
Actually, I'm using TCPDF in Joomla! 2.5. Everything is OK and examples work well (i.e. when I test `/localhost/tcpdf/example_001.php` everything is alright). Anyway, when I start to use TCPDF in my own codes, the output PDF file is corrupted. Here is a clue, when I opened PDF file with an editor I found out that `header` and `body` of my HTML code are printed before content of PDF. Where can I realize where these lines come from? How can I stop it? Is is possible that all of these be due to of my used template in Joomla!?

Please help me with this silly problem. Again, all I want is just preventing TCPDF from printing HTML codes (i.e. header and body) in output PDF.

---

By the way, I've already checked a lot of stuff on the Internet, but none of them could be helpful. Like:
[TCPDF creates damaged pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707405/tcpdf-creates-damaged-pdf)

---

Here is my code (actually is it the first example of tcpdf). Assume I've put this code in my program. Now, when this part of code is executed, while the program is generating the PDF file (by `output` command) the codes which are related to my template will be inserted into this file.

```
    // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
$docRoot = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/';
require_once( $docRoot . 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php' );
    require_once('tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 001');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 001', PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
$pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set default font subsetting mode
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// Set font
// dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
// print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
// helvetica or times to reduce file size.
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

// Add a page
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->AddPage();

// set text shadow effect
$pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));

// Set some content to print
$html = <<<EOD
<h1>Welcome to <a href="http://www.tcpdf.org" style="text-decoration:none;background-color:#CC0000;color:black;">&nbsp;<span style="color:black;">TC</span><span style="color:white;">PDF</span>&nbsp;</a>!</h1>
<i>This is the first example of TCPDF library.</i>
<p>This text is printed using the <i>writeHTMLCell()</i> method but you can also use: <i>Multicell(), writeHTML(), Write(), Cell() and Text()</i>.</p>
<p>Please check the source code documentation and other examples for further information.</p>
<p style="color:#CC0000;">TO IMPROVE AND EXPAND TCPDF I NEED YOUR SUPPORT, PLEASE <a href="http://sourceforge.net/donate/index.php?group_id=128076">MAKE A DONATION!</a></p>
EOD;

// Print text using writeHTMLCell()
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// Close and output PDF document
// This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
$pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');

//============================================================+
// END OF FILE
//============================================================+
```

Comment: Showing your code may help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I've edited my question so that now it includes my code, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Joomla but I'm guessing that it is using PHP's output buffering as part of it's HTML rendering process. Try calling `ob_end_clean()` before you call `$pdf->Output()` and see if that makes a difference.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php

If that doesn't help then I think we'll need a Joomla person to provide an answer to this question.

Comment: I've had same problem in pure PHP project and this solution did the trick. Thanks